# Check if letter i occurs an even amount of times in string

Tags: java, regex

I want to use Java regular expressions to count the number of occurrences of the character `i` in a string and see if the count is an even number. (Note that zero is also considered an even number.) Here is an example string.

```
iuhuihuijdjoiuio
```

The above string contains five occurrences of the character `i` which is an odd number.

Here is the regular expression that I thought to try:

```
(i*){2})*
```

Comment: Rather than post how long you've tried, information that doesn't help clarify your actual problem, much better would be to show your own best attempts and tell the details of the problems that you're having with it, information *does* help to clarify your problem and your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and *show* your code as well as tell the details of your problem. Please review the [ask] link. Your question is now closed but it may be re-opened and answered, but only if you improve it considerably.

Comment: ((i*){2})* That was my idea but didnot work

Comment: Again, please read the [ask] link to see how to *substantially* improve this question. Best of luck to you!

Comment: The problem is my english is not good, and I dont understand that and my mother language is not on google translate.

Comment: @oiujoijoi Please check, if my edit of your question is ok. Regarding your issue [see this idea](https://regex101.com/r/TxyNG6/1).

Comment: You can use the following regular expression: `^(?:(?:[^i]*i){2})*[^i]*$`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QCRzr6/1). Notice that at the link I used `^(?:(?:[^i\n]*i){2})*[^i\n]*$` merely do be able to show results for several strings.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Your solution is brilliant. Please consider posting it as an answer where you can also explain your RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Someone already put a solution using Regex in the comments, but here's one that uses Java instead. I haven't compiled it so I'm not sure if it works.

```java
public boolean even_count(String str, char c) {
    int count = 0; // Make variable count

    for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++) { // Iterate through string
        if(str.charAt(i) == c) // If the current position of string is the char we're seraching for
            count++; // Add one to the count variable
    }

    return count % 2 == 0; // Return wheather count is even or not.
}
```